# node http-server stops with exception when using proxy Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: angularjs, node.js, httpserver

I'm using node package http-server to serve my web pages locally. Suddenly it started failing to connect to the proxy server. Searched in stackoverflow but didn't get satisfied answer for this scenario. Please help.

Here are the commands and logs:

> http-server -p 8000 app/ --proxy localhost:3000
>   Starting up http-server, serving app/
>   Available on:
>     http:127.0.0.1:8000
>     http:192.168.1.6:8000
>   Unhandled requests will be served from: localhost:3000
>   Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
>
> [Mon, 04 Jul 2016 13:29:27 GMT] "POST /candidates/resumes"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
>   /Users/tushar/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:119
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 0.0.11.184:80 - Local (192.168.1.6:58636)
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
>       at connect (net.js:843:14)
>       at net.js:985:7
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:63:16)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:82:10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. My bad. The proxy address has to be inside the quotation mark. No idea when it has become mandatory to be quoted. Here is the example command if it helps anyone -

> http-server app/ -p 8000 --proxy `'http://localhost:3000'`

or simply the following (default port and current-dir instead of specifying a folder 'app')

> http-server --proxy `'http://localhost:3000'`